# How do i select specific elements from div?

Tags: java, html, jsoup, selector

I want to get the date from this div:

```
<div class="pandatacontcol" style=" width:160px;">
    <h6>Date Qualified</h6>
    <p id="QualDate34868684">2013-03-08 12:04:01</p>
</div>
```

so output would be: `2013-03-08`

I tried to do like that:

```
elements = doc.select("p[id^=\"QualDate\"]");
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Some key information is missing from your question: What HTML parser are you using? Myself I use jsoup. And how doesn't it work? If you're using a parser, are you getting the `text()` after the select?

Comment: As @HovercraftFullOfEels suggested, use jsoup. By the way, when you ask a question on Stackoverflow, avoid begging + clarify your question  as keep in mind this question is going to be viewed by other people as well :)

Comment: i use Jsoup. to check if i get what needed i use
System.out.println(elements.text()); 
when i do

elements = doc.select("div.pandatacontcol");

i get full div and i just want that specific element

and as i said 

elements = doc.select("p[id^=\"QualDate\"]");

doesnt return it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try without quote marks

```
doc.select("p[id^=QualDate]");
```

Value of attribute is set inside quote marks `<tag attribute="value">`, but those quote marks are not part of value.